Riemann Sum of $\frac{1}{x^2}$
I am a beginner and I am trying to evaluate the Riemann sum $\sum^{n}_{i=1}f(c_i)\Delta x_i$ of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ on the interval $[1,2]$, but I end up with a limit approaching zero. I cannot see where I am making a mistake.These are the steps I have taken:
S1) Creating a partition with subintervals of equal length:$$\Delta x_i=\Delta x=\frac{2-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$
S2) writing the division points in terms of the first point the length of the subinterval: $$x_0=1, x_i=1+\frac{i}{n}$$
S3) the Riemann sum. I take the tag to be $c_i=\sqrt {x_ix_{i-1}}$:
$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}f(c_i)\Delta x_i=\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{x_ix_{i-1}}\frac{1}{n}$$
S4) The limit:$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{x_ix_{i-1}}\frac{1}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{x_ix_{i-1}} $$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{i}{n})(1+\frac{i-1}{n})}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{n^2}{(n+i)(n+i-1)}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{(n+i)(n+i-1)}=0$$
But the definite integral of the function on this interval equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Why do you think the last limit is $0$? It is indeed $1/2$, by calculating the sum by telescoping.

@KangyeonMoon I thought in each term, there is the first power of $n$ in the numerator and the second power in the denominator. I think I see my mistake. There is an infinite number of terms, so it does not approach zero, right? Stupid of me! But still don't know how to extract the telescoping terms there.

In $x_0=1, x_i=1+\frac{i}{n}$ you don't need to define $x_0$ apart, it's just the term $x_i$ when $i=0$.

Your mistake is at the limit.$$\frac{1}{(n+i)(n+i-1)}=\frac{1}{n+i-1}-\frac{1}{n+i}$$ So the summation equals to $$\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{1}{n+i-1}-\frac{1}{n+i})=(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$$So, the limit equals to $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$

The mistake is not at the summation. The summation is right. The problem is the limit.

You are right, I've changed it in my answer
